# IPython jump to error in vi / Vim?

Tags: debugging, vim, vi, ipython

When using Vim to develop C code, it's possible to run `:make` then `:cp` to jump directly to compiler errors in the code.

I wonder if there is any similar functionality when using IPython with Vim as the editor, so that when an error occurs I can type something that starts the editor, opens the file, and goes directly to the line?

Comment: Don't have an answer, but you can always add `from IPython import embed; embed()` somewhere in your code and once the interpreter hits that line it will open ipython.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible for syntax errors, but I don't know if the code to do that still works - it's been around for some time without any tests. To try it, set this in your `ipython_config.py` file:

```
c.TerminalInteractiveShell.autoedit_syntax = True
```